# Is there any way to automate the transfer of objects from the old bucket to the new bucket when renaming in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Refactoring the names of buckets deletes the resource. Maybe there is a fancy way to automate object transfer

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no practical way to automate this. You can however [use the AWS CLI to sync the bucket's contents](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html) to a local storage or to a temporary S3 bucket, then perform the rename, then sync back the contents from the temp storage to the new bucket.

Alternatively you can use the console to select the objects, right-click, copy, then paste in another bucket.